# JQuery Responsive Datatable doesn't work if table is ever empty

Tags: datatable, datatables, responsive

I have a responsive datatable defined as follows:

```
function loadCancellations(date) {
    $('#cancellations').dataTable({
        bDestroy: true,
        bProcessing: false,
        bServerSide: false,
        bAutoWidth: false,
        ajax: {
            url: 'Modules/Bookings/',
            data: {date: date, type: 'cancelled'}
        },
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        iDisplayLength: 50,
        bLengthChange: false,
        bPaginate: false,
        bFilter: false,
        bSort: true,
        sDom: 't',
        rowId: 6,
        columns: [/*responsive column information*/],
        order: [[0, 'asc'],[1, 'asc']],
        asStripeClasses: ['', 'altrow'],
        language: {
            emptyTable: 'No cancelled bookings for this day'
        },
        fnCreatedRow: function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            // last column replaced with buttons
        }
    });
}
```

This function is called when the value of a datepicker changes, so it always refreshes the table with the cancelled bookings on the selected day. There are six columns (plus the buttons), two are always hidden until the row is expanded using the responsive interface in the first column, and I've tested it multiple times and it works fine.

*except*

If the table is ever empty, the responsive interface never works again. Instead it kicks a console error that says `TypeError: a[0].aoData[this[0]] is undefined`. So if it loads full, then I load a day that doesn't have any, and then I load another day that has some, the responsive plugin breaks. It doesn't matter whether I then destroy and re-initialize the datatable, it simply refuses to work. I can even go back to a date that had working rows - they don't work any more.

Does anyone have any ideas for a solution to this?

Comment: You are not using the responsive extension at all. I guess you are using child rows and the error is in the code where you are injecting / removing child rows.

Comment: Yes, I am using the responsive extension. I removed the column declarations for the sake of keeping the post brief, but I assure you the extension is there and in use.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin I was using was out of date. This was solved in a later version. I should have checked this before posting, and I feel shame for it.